# Absolute and relative paths

Tags: themes, paths

Hello I am new to this and i want to export my local made website on xampp and add to hosting ( live ) and i need relative paths in theme and everything but i have Absolute how to change it?

Comment: Absolute paths where? Paths to what? Why do you need relative paths? Can you share examples?

Comment: WordPress is using a lot absolute path in the database too.
You need to perform a search and replace thanks to [wp-cli](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) for example or use a third party plugin like https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.